# .htaccess - DocumentRoot for subdomain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain_name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain_name.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain_name\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/retailers/
RewriteRule (.*) /retailers/$1 [L]
```

When I Enter

1. www.domain_name.com    --Works Fine
2. domain_name.com        --Works Fine
3. sub.domain_name.com    --Works Fine [sub means any valid subdomain name]

The Problem is 
When I Type sub.domain.com/admin [admin is the folder in /www/retailers/admin], it changes url to sub.domain_name.com/retailers/admin. How ever it should display sub.domain_name.com/admin in the Address Bar.

I donno how can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because `admin` is directory and `mod_dir` is forcing a trailing slash. You can have your .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(domain_name\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# force a trailing slash for directories
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain_name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/retailers/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain_name\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!retailers/).*)$ retailers/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It is not working.
Now the subdomain part send internal server error
sub.domain.com was working fine before.

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser? Did it add a trailing slash when you got 500?

Comment: sub.domain.com       [not working]
sub.domain.com/      [not working]

Comment: sub.domain_name.com/admin also not working, sub.domain_name.com/admin/ also not working,

Comment: I've tested these exact rules on my Apache and it worked fine. Make sure you don't have any other rule while testing this.

Comment: Yes It worked now after you Edition. Thanks anubhava